# How to put blanks in Vim 'comments' option

Tags: vim

I am trying to control multi-line comments for the Lua language in Vim.

If, in insert mode, I input the sequence:

```
--[[<CR>hello<CR>goodbye<CR>]]
```

Then I want the final text to look like this:

```
--[[
  hello
  goodbye
]]
```

So far, I have not been able to find a setting of `'comments'` to accomplish this.
In particular, the `m` (middle of 3-part comment) does not seem to accept a space (let alone 2 spaces) as its string.

I tried this:

```
set com=s:--[[,m:\ \ ,e:]],:--
```

But there are no leading spaces whatsoever. I get:

```
--[[
hello
goodbye
]]
```

Note, if I add a non-blank character, it *does* work (kind of):

```
set com=s2:--[[,m:.,e:]],:--

--[[
. hello
. goodbye
. ]]
```

I am especially confused because the Vim help page says:

> Any blank space in the text before and after the {string} is part of
>   the {string}, so do not include leading or trailing blanks unless the
>   blanks are a required part of the comment string.

They way I read that, it says that any blanks I put in `comment=` are taken literally as blanks, and not ignored. But in my case, they seem to be ignored...

Any advice, here?